# EmberJS: Exclude a folder from being watched for changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

How can I exclude a particular folder from being watched in Ember CLI?

Comment: Do you want the folder's contents to be built in the first place? If not, https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-funnel can exclude folders from the build entirely.

Comment: How do I target and exclude a folder within my `public` folder? I've tried multiple path combinations but nothing seem to actually exclude.

Comment: Do you mean to exclude a folder for live reload?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't want a folder to be watched for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my `ember-cli-build.js` file with the necessary changes to unwatch the "public" directory.

```
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'),
  ENV = require('./config/environment')(process.env.EMBER_ENV),
  Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel'),
  dependencies = require('./config/dependencies'),
  UnwatchedDir = require('broccoli-source').UnwatchedDir;

module.exports = function (defaults) {
  const app = new EmberApp(defaults, ENV.options),
    imports = dependencies.imports;

  for (let i = 0; i < imports.length; i++) {
    app.import(imports[i]);
  }

  const compilationAssets = [],
    funnels = dependencies.funnels;

  Object.keys(funnels).forEach(function (key) {
    const options = funnels[key],
      funnelObj = new Funnel(key, options);

    compilationAssets.push(funnelObj);
  });

  // This does the magic
  if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'development' || process.env.EMBER_ENV == 'test') {
    app.trees.public = new UnwatchedDir('public');
  }

  return app.toTree(compilationAssets);
};
```